# Delphi / Rad Studio 10.4 - TSimpleDataSet: cannot expand Connection and DataSet property

Tags: delphi

when I use a TSimpleDataSet, the IDE cannot allow me to expand Connection and DataSet property.

See the image below. I don't have the arrow to expand properties but only on Connection and DataSet.

[image: Screenshot with missing arrow]

Please give me support!

Answer (score 1):

Your project needs to contain a TSqlConnection component before you can set the `Connection` property of a TSimpleDataSet.

Do this:

1. Start a new VCL project.
2. Add a TSqlConnection and a TSqlQuery to the form.
3. Configure the TSqlConnection to access a Sqlite database on your system.
4. Set the `SqlConnection` of SqlQuery1 to SqlConnection1.

Now ...

5. Add a TSimpleDataSet to the form.
6. Set the `Connection` property of SimpleDataSet1 to SqlConnection1.  This answers your first point.
7. Notice that you still can't change the `DataSet` property of SimpleDataSet1.  That's working as designed, because it is only supposed to use this internally-created dataset.
8. Open the `DataSet` property of SimpleDataSet1 and set its `CommandText` property to do a SELECT query against one of the tables in the Sqlite databaase.
9. Set `SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.Active` to True.  That'h how you use TSimpleDataSet's `DataSet` property.

Next, see https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TSimpleDataSet and https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/SimpleDS.TSimpleDataSet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
Unfortunately even following your guide still doesn't work.

Could it be a RadStudio configuration problem?

Comment: Well, if you make the effort to explain exacly what "still doesn't work", perhaps that will solve it.  But just saying it doesn't work doesn't convey any useful infornation whatsoever.  And no, I don't think it's a configuration problem.

Comment: The problem is simple: when I try to expand Connecton and DataSet property, the arrows is missing and i cannot expand to see properties.

I try the same project in another PC and it works perfectly. In my company only my pc have this problem, in the other 4 PC it works.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Delphi on your machine?

Comment: No because we use a lot of components and packages, so I would try to solve with current installation. :(
The last way will be the re-installation!